# Score documents by term frequency alone and not inverse document frequency in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When Iam searching for a particular term in my index, I'm getting the results with less occurrence of the searched term  than the the results with higher occurrence of the searched term.
 Is there any way such that I can score documents based on the term frequency alone and not the inverse document frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Actually the scoring algorithm depends on the type of query, usually it is indeed TF-IDF but you can use [script scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html), you simply write a simple script that determines how the score should be calculated. You simply return in the script the field which is inside the document which represents the term frequency.

You can find more info how to do that [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html).